# What's wrong with my logic in this iteration of list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I was expecting `['jelly%s'% x*x for x in range(1,11)]` would give me a list of jellyx*x, but it returned the following value.

```
['jelly1', 'jelly2jelly2', 'jelly3jelly3jelly3', 'jelly4jelly4jelly4jelly4', 'jelly5jelly5jelly5jelly5jelly5', 'jelly6jelly6jelly6jelly6jelly6jelly6', 'jelly7jelly7jelly7jelly7jelly7jelly7jelly7', 'jelly8jelly8jelly8jelly8jelly8jelly8jelly8jelly8', 'jelly9jelly9jelly9jelly9jelly9jelly9jelly9jelly9jelly9', 'jelly10jelly10jelly10jelly10jelly10jelly10jelly10jelly10jelly10jelly10']
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the expression:

```
'jelly%s'% x*x
```

This is equivalent to:

```
('jelly%s'%x)*x
```

Because the `%` and `*` operators have the [same precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Precedence just means which operators get evaluated first in an expression. Operators with higher precedence "bind" before operators with lower precedence, operators with equal precedence get evaluated left-to-right. This is similar to mathematics, so:

```
>>> 1 + 10 * 10 # * has higher precedence
101
>>> (1 + 10) * 10 # we can force + to happen first
110
```

Note, the arithmetic operators have the precedence that is typical for arithmetic operators from mathematics.

And finally, you might not know, but with sequence-types (which includes `str`, `list`, `tuple`, the `*` operator causes a "repitition operation", so:

```
>>> 'juan'*1
'juan'
>>> 'juan'*2
'juanjuan'
>>> 'juan'*3
'juanjuanjuan'
```

So, to get what you want, try:

```
['jelly%s'% (x*x) for x in range(1,11)]
```

Alternatively, you could use the `.format` method on strings:

```
>>> ['jelly{}'.format(x*x) for x in range(1,11)]
['jelly1', 'jelly4', 'jelly9', 'jelly16', 'jelly25', 'jelly36', 'jelly49', 'jelly64', 'jelly81', 'jelly100']
```

Or better even, use f-strings in Python 3.6:

```
>>> [f'jelly{x*x}' for x in range(1,11)]
['jelly1', 'jelly4', 'jelly9', 'jelly16', 'jelly25', 'jelly36', 'jelly49', 'jelly64', 'jelly81', 'jelly100']
```

Comment: hey that's true! but still i don't understand what do you mean by 'have the same precedence'. i understand the logic order went wrong in my expression but why it resulted like that? thx a lot!

Comment: @XYlaven ah yes, I'll add further explanation

Comment: @XYlaven i've added more details

Answer (score 2):

You can also do :

```
['jelly%s' % num for num in [x*x for x in range(1,11)]]
```

Will give :

```
OUT : ['jelly1', 'jelly4', 'jelly9', 'jelly16', 'jelly25', 'jelly36', 'jelly49', 'jelly64', 'jelly81', 'jelly100']
```

Here, the `[x*x for x in range(1,11)]]` will give `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]` which you then use in your string.

For more explanation on the behaviour of the OP's code (due to `precedence` of operators `*` and `%`) , have a look at [Juanpa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46509568/7550472).

Comment: thx a lot, but could you plz explain why my code works like that?

Comment: That is as [Juanpa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46509568/7550472) explained. Due to `precedence`

Comment: Sure, glad to help.